# run APDU commands on NTag424 DNA

Tags: nfc, apdu

I am currently developing an application using Flutter to write to an NTAG424 DNA NFC tag; however, I am encountering some issues with the APDU commands. I am unable to execute a simple APDU command.

For instance, when I send the write command "908D000019010E0000120000FF0506E1050080828300000000000000000000" I receive a response of 0x919D.
Similarly, when I use the command "004300E0000100C1F1212000004300009100" the response I receive is 0x6700.

these are example commands from https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf

Additionally, I would like to know how to set keys for authentication.

p.s. I do not own any hardware/software NFC reader/writer (except for my flutter app).

Best regards.

Comment: As per NTAG424 datasheet a status code "9Dh" can mean "PICC level (MF) is selected." so I'm assuming you didn't select the (one and only) application on the the tag before you are trying to read or write to the tag. Your seconds "command" is a **response** to a "Get File Settings" command. Regarding "set key for authentication": as you already found the feature & hints document just follow the personalization section - step 16 is "Change Key - ApplicationKey 0x02 (Using AES-128 Key diversification)". B.t.w.: you need to run an "authenticateEV2First" first before running these commands.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Michael Fehr. I receive the response 0x9140 (no such key) when I run "authenticateEV2First". The example command is 9071000002000000.

Comment: The response "No such key" is resulting when you try to authenticateEV2First on PICC level (= no application was selected before) because there is is NO KEY NUMBER 00 on PICC level. Again: run the "select application" command before trying to run any read/write/change commands.